Forest plot using HR data on R
This is my data. My plan is to find mean for HR using random-effect, with I^2 and overall effect and weightage (%). I tried many ways but could not find the correct way to produce the forest plot. I could not find a correct package for HR.Naturally log-transformed
HR and standard errors were calculatedto pool the HR. A random-effects generic inverse variance method was used to generate pooled HR.
# Generate LVEF dataset
studyID <- c("Lange et al. (2023)", "Backhaus et al. (2022b)", "Podlesnikar et al. (2020)", "Kanaji et al. (2019)", "Reindl et al. (2019)", "Eitel et al. (2018)")
HR <- c(0.94, 0.94, 0.922, 0.98, 0.95, 0.94)
lower_CI <- c(0.91, 0.92, 0.882, 0.95, 0.92, 0.92)
upper_CI <- c(0.96, 0.96, 0.965, 1.01, 0.97, 0.96)
p_values <- c(0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.14, 0.001, 0.001)
MACE <- c(41, 77, 25, 23, 46,94)

I want a forest plot similar like this
